# Installing Barrel caused an issue which doesn't go away

Tags: applications, jailbreak, iphone

I installed and ran Barrel 2 on my iPhone and set the new effect. I also needed to move a group of apps and made my icons toggle. Then all my apps stopped working. I uninstalled it but the issue still remains.

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "all your apps stopped working"?  Nothing will start at all?  Are there any error messages, or indications of what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If rebooting the phone didn't work, a system refresh using iTunes will certainly fix the problem.

You can try installing and then uninstalling Barrel again, in case the uninstall or original install failed at some point.  This should clean it back up.  But if it doesn't, then a clean reinstall of iOS will do it.